# Laravel 4.2: Routig controller with alias?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to Route to my controller with alias but for readability, and less code I'd like to use `Route::controller('/login','LoginController')`. Is there a way to use both? Or is there any other way to reference a method in my controller if I use this Route::controller syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this rather easily. You can use the syntax `Route::controller(...)` and instead of using `route('route_name')` to get the route by alias use `action(Controller@method)`. Although it would be still nice to have aliases.

Answer (score 0):

just use resource route it will automatically create these routes:

- index
- create
- show
- edit
- update
- destroy

add this to `routes.php`

```
Route::resource('someroute', 'YourController');
```

you also can add exception for those 6 routes. can refer [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)